# UWP calculate time until charged

Tags: c#, uwp, battery

I have access to the Battery API for UWP and can display the current battery percentage identical to the system percentage. However, I am wondering how does windows calculate the time until fully charged?

I know very little about the formulas and units of measure in electronics.

I have looked up different formulas but again they are using units that I don't understand and I really don't understand what the Battery class is giving me.

My max -> 64250 MilliWattHours
Rate -> 8516

So 64250/8516 = ~7.544
Is ~7.5 in minutes, in which case the Windows UI is wrong?

Windows Reports 5 minutes remaining

So here is some code:

```
if (report.Status == BatteryStatus.Charging)
            {
                var report = sender.GetReport(); //<-- where sender is Type<Battery>
                //(double)TryGetValue(report.FullChargeCapacityInMilliwattHours)

//(double)TryGetValue(report.ChargeRateInMilliwatts) <-- I don't understand how to use this with the max value of the battery to get the rate at which is is charging per Hr, Min, etc.
                    var rate = //Formula goes here
                    var remainingTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find the rate(charging/discharging current) at which your battery is being charged/discharged(in order to find remaining time on battery) also the total capacity of the battery to estimate the remaining time. If you have these two parameters its pretty simple to calculate it.

> time left is seconds = (capacity to be charged in mA * 60 * 60)/(charging current in mA).

Similar in the case of WH.

Comment: Battery gives me a rate, and the max capacity, but the max is in hours and rate has no units?

Comment: report.DesignCapacityInMilliwattHours will give you the total capacity in mWh and report.RemainingCapacityInMilliwattHours will give you the remaining capacity and you can find out the mWh to be charged by subtracting remaining from total and substitute it on the equation.

Comment: Can you provide context to the units all this is in? So I take max millwatthour - currentmillwatthour. I take that value and multiple by x60x60 then divide that by my rate? And that returns?

Comment: This will give you the seconds left till full charge. If you want hours you don't need to multiply with 3600. its just (watt hour/watt) = hours remaining. Also the charging rate will not be same if you keep the system on because it will take some current to keep the system on and it will change according to the CPU load and other factors. so you have to take an average charging rate. That is why windows is showing a different value.

Comment: I understand their is some tug back from the system and that is why monitoring the battery percentage and charge cannot be perfectly accurate because simply performing the calculations uses CPU resources and some amount of power on top of the overall system drain.

Comment: A possible solution would be to store the charge rate in a double array and every tick of the battery update add the rate into this array, if 5 are present take the average and remove one.